# Was I attacked or my identity found out?

Tags: anonymity, deanonymization, attacks

I am new to TOR and not very tech savvy.  While using TOR to set up an email account, I found that I had to constantly to solve puzzles for verification. Sometimes websites would not allow me access, saying my computer may have a virus as it was getting too many requests.  What freaked me out was when an ad on the side of the page showed an ad for a show I watch thru a streaming service.  At the time I think I had been using Chrome for searches that didn't need anonymity... So I'm wondering if the TOR browser and Chrome were able to share info, or if someone figured out my identity? Thanks for any help you can give in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a captcha glitch, quite a common one. It's OK - some sites are using overreaching protection, it does backfire like that even without using Tor. Tor Browser and Chrome *by themselves* are two separated processes, but if you've used an add-on inside both of them that logs you into itself in some way, i.e. via facebook, google account, e.t.c. - this can happen *via that particular add-on*